# Change Customized horizontal stepper's font color

Tags: material-ui

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LprxW.png)

I'd want to add a customised horizontal stepper, but the text colour is too near to the background colour; how can I modify the font color?

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stepper/#customized-horizontal-stepper

Comment: Please share some of your code

Comment: https://sourceb.in/YthZ8h2A8s

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color with sx prop:

```
<Stepper
  ...
  sx={{ "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": { color: "red" } }} //or any color
>
```